# R: labels() command doesn't work when trying to set x axis labels onto a histogram

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

Simplifying and trying to make my error reproducible, my code is the following, it generates a histogram and set x axis and y axis afterwards:

```
    set.seed(100)

    dist <- data.frame(rnorm(200, sd = 300000))

    histogram <- hist(dist$rnorm.200., col = "orange", breaks = 100, main = "VaR distribution", xlab = "P&L", axes = FALSE)

    axis(1, at = seq(min(dist), max(dist), length = 7))
    labels(formatC(seq(min(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, max(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, length = 7), format = "d", digits = 0))

    axis(2, at = seq(from = 0, to = max(histogram$counts), by = 5))
    labels(formatC(seq(from = 0, to = max(histogram$counts), by = 5), format = "d"))
```

The command to set labels on axis y works, but the x axis labels command doesn't, which is the following:

```
axis(1, at = seq(min(dist), max(dist), length = 7))
    labels(formatC(seq(min(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, max(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, length = 7), format = "d", digits = 0))
```

instead of getting a sequence of 7 values of `dist$norm.200.` divided by 1000000 and without decimals, I get the default values set by `histogram()` function.

Could anyone help me?

Edition: Neither the y axis labels command nor x works, I thank it did in my original code because it matched causally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `labels` as an argument of the `axis()` function, not as a separate function. Something like this:

```
set.seed(100)

dist <- data.frame(rnorm(200, sd = 300000))

histogram <- hist(dist$rnorm.200., col = "orange", breaks = 100, main = "VaR distribution", xlab = "P&L", axes = FALSE)

axis(1, at = seq(min(dist), max(dist), length = 7), labels = formatC(seq(min(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, max(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, length = 7), format = "d", digits = 0))

axis(2, at = seq(from = 0, to = max(histogram$counts), by = 5), labels = (formatC(seq(from = 0, to = max(histogram$counts), by = 5), format = "d")))
```

Also, you should realize `formatC(seq(min(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, max(dist$rnorm.200.)/1000000, length = 7), format = "d", digits = 0)` only returns zeroes, so perhaps you'd like to give some more attention towards what these labels actually should be. (Perhaps divide by 100000 instead?)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was reading the definition of `labels()` function and I found that if you pass through a vector it's the same as executing `seq.along(vector)`. Do yo know what argument should I use to get the values of `vector` in the x axis instead of the `seq.along(vector)` values?

Comment: I found the error, I was not using labels as an argument, I was using labels as a function within axis

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ggplot2 approach. I myself find the code to be more readible, an so: easier to maintain.

```
set.seed(100)
dist <- data.frame(rnorm(200, sd = 300000))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dist, aes( x = dist[,1] ) ) + 
  geom_histogram( bins = 100, color = "black", fill = "orange" ) +
  scale_x_continuous( labels = function(x){x / 100000} ) + 
  labs( title = "VaR distribution",
        x = "P&L",
        y = "Frequency" )
```

[image]